# IPv6 addresses and Hexadecimal: If F is equal to 16, how would 16 binary digits equate to FFFF?

Tags: hex, decimal, ipv6, radix

1111111111111111 = FFFF
Each F in this scenario is clearly only representing 4 bits.

Would 1 F not suffice in this situation?

Forgive me if this is a bit of a simpleton question, but it is just really bothering me. Thank you!

Comment: In programming numbers start from `0`

Answer (score 2):

`F` = 15, `FF` = 255.

It's like asking "if 1 = one, why do we need 11 to mean *eleven*?"

Answer (score 0):

F (in hexa) equal to 15 (and not 16).
FF (in hexa) equal to 255.

BTW, 16 in decimal is 10 in hexa.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Doesn't  the counting start at zero, making F 16, not zero?

Comment: sorry, making F 16 not 15. since it is a base 16 system

Answer (score 0):

> If F is equal to 16...

That is incorrect. Each `f` is four bits, so `f` hexadecimal is `15` decimal.